# Can't get Apache-like multiviews functionality in nginx

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, multiview, pathinfo, multiviews

I've been trying for a few days to get apache-style multiviews working with path_info with no luck. I'm using nginx/1.2.1 and php5-fpm 2.4.0. My goal is to be able to visit `example.com/product/48/my-product-name` where `product` translates to `product.php` and everything proceeding interpreted as the path_info.

I've devised a regex to split the URI into `product` and `/48/my-product-name` which seems to work on paper but doesn't work in my config:

`^(.+?)(\/.*)$`

I've used this with fastcgi_split_path_info while defining fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME etc... and many more combinations.

**EDIT:** I just realised this regex wont work with with a url such as: `example.com/dir/script/path/info` it wont be translated to `dir/script.php`, and `/path/info`, but `/dir.php`, and `/script/path/info`. I'm starting to wonder if this is even possible to overcome?

I'm new to nginx and want to try it out since it apparently is much faster and less resource-hungry than Apache, but I can't see why this would be such a hard thing to achieve. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.